# What's the best way to select the same region on multiple meshes?

Tags: mesh, selection-tools

Let's say there's an area of space, and I want to remove all vertices which occur in this region. It's easy to do this for one mesh; I just go into edit mode, select and delete. Fine.

Now, I have a second mesh, and I want to delete all vertices which occur in exactly the same area of space for which I deleted vertices on the first one. My initial thought was to select both meshes to begin with, go into edit mode, select and delete. However, it seems that edit mode only works for one mesh at a time.

So, is there an easy way to do this without resorting to CSG or scripting?

Comment: Please add more information, if you don't want to post images of the actual objects make up a collection of dummy objects with the core features - allowing you to annotate areas of interest. Else you may get some quite elaborate answers which don't work for your case. If I understood the constraints of the problem better I'd likely offer a scripted solution.

Comment: A scripted solution? Maybe you should re-read the question. Two out of three of the respondents below understood it just fine.

Comment: if they work that's fine. no sweat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go into edit mode for each of your meshes and assign 1 vertex group for all vertices for each mesh. Also name them:

   [image]
2. Now merge all the meshes into 1 with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>. It will preserve the vert groups:

   [image]
3. Delete the vertices you want.
4. Separate your meshes back with selecting each vertex group and <kbd>P</kbd>>Selection:

   [image]

Comment: Great answer, exactly what I was looking for! A helpful lesson for me in the power of Blender -- now that I've started using vertex groups I imagine it will help me do all sorts of other things.

Comment: However, that "P" for the separation operator should be lowercase. Took me a while to figure that out. I can't edit it because there's a minimum of 6-characters to submit an edit. Jerryno, can you fix that please?

Comment: @foobarbecue well on my keyboard the button has uppercase P so the image of the button is correct, isn't it?

Comment: I see, you would put "shift + P" if the user was supposed to hold shift. Ok, fair enough. I guess there aren't really uppercase and lowercase hotkeys, just with shift and without shift.

Answer (score 1):

Multiedit addon, select objects you want to delete vertices, press Multiedit Enter button, select vertices, delete, press Multiedit Exit button.

http://www.blendernation.com/2014/09/29/edit-multiple-objects-at-once-with-the-multiedit-addon/

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this solves my problem, but I've accepted the other answer because it does so without an add-on and actually provides more flexibility. Good to know this exists, though, +1 since it will probably save me time in the future.

Answer (score 0):

If you have two same objects/meshes delete one and add mirror modifier :)

Or if those meshes are two separate objects you could go in to object data of second one (which does not have deleted vertices) and just chose object data of first one, you can do this only when you in object mode so when you do this second object will also occupy same space as firs one, just select one and move it, go in edit mode and select only one vertecs and see whats hepening :)

[image]

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure I totally understood your answer, but it doesn't seem relevant to what I want to do. The two meshes are very different (actually they are lidar surveys of ice caves taken in different years), but they overlap in space. I just want to use the select tool to select vertices on both objects.

Comment: Can you post picture in edit mode as example of regions which you would like to select, downlaod https://www.dropbox.com/s/98izazqn0q1lrxy/same_object_data.blend?dl=0 that file and see what Im talking about, go in edit mode, pick vertex and move or delete it